# Best Practice When Storing Dynamic Fields in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I have a form with inputs fields which can duplicated as many times as the user wants. Eg. - Educational Qualifications field, user can put in just 1 educational qualification or add 10 of them, what is the best way to store these in a database. I know i can serialise them in PHP or convert data inputted in those fields into JSON and then store it. But I know that is not ideal or the best practice. Can anyone guide me on the best way to it?

["Dyanamic Form Input Example"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgCAu.png)

Comment: do you want to add more fields with the degree  and college/institute?

Comment: More fields when clicking add more on front end would be added through javascript, which I know how to do. But in the backend, inside a mysql database what is the best way to store that data once the form is submitted?

Comment: You must also think about how the "more" will be accessed.  JSON is clumsy; more rows in a table is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a table PersonDetails to store the details of a person. Donot store Education details in this table as there is a one to many relationship (one person can have many education detail rows). Create another table EducationQualification to store each education qualification and link both tables using 'personId'. Additionally you can also create foreign key constraint in 'personId' column of 'EducationQualification' table.

```
create table PersonDetails(personId integer primary key, name varchar(30));
insert into PersonDetails(personId,name) values(1, "praveen");
insert into PersonDetails values(2, 'naga');
insert into PersonDetails values(3, 'surya');

create table EducationQualification(QualificationID integer primary key, QualificationName varchar(30), personId integer);
insert into EducationQualification values (1, 'schooling', 1);
insert into EducationQualification values (2, 'degree', 1);
insert into EducationQualification values (3, 'postgraduate', 2);
insert into EducationQualification values (4, 'graduate', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

hello create a table user and a table user_qualificatin, the useId from user table is foreign key in user_qualification table, ex you can set this id to autoincrement, and increments when ever you append a new qualification.